# What's the difference between "gld/st_throughput" and "dram_read/write_throughput" metrics?

Tags: memory, cuda, metrics, throughput

In the CUDA visual profiler, version 5, I know that the "gld/st_requested_throughput" are the requested memory throughput of application. However, when I try to find the actual throughput of hardware, I am confused because there are two pairs of metrics which seem to be qualified, and they are "gld/st_throughput" and "dram_read/write_throughput". Which pair is actually the hardware throughput? And what does the other serve as?

Answer (score 2):

`gld/st_throughput` includes transactions served by the L1 and L2 caches. While `dram_read/write_throughput` is the throughput between L2 and device memory. So, each global memory access counts towards `gld/st_throughput` but only requests that missed both the L1 and L2 caches  count towards `dram_read/write_throughput`.

I haven't found a good overview of the counters anywhere. Wish NVIDIA would provide that...

Comment: There is a Metrics Reference [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#metrics-reference).  Not trying to start a discussion about whether it is good or not,  I'm sure it could be better.

Comment: IMHO no transaction is served directly from the global memory. All accesses to global memory go through L2, including copies to/from CPU 
host. [Found at.](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/cuda_webinars_GlobalMemory.pdf)

Comment: @stuhlo: Thanks. My answer was poorly worded on that point. Will fix.

Comment: @Roger Dahl@stuhlo: Thank you both, I've got it!