# What's the difference between "requested global load throughput" and "global load throughput" in CUDA

Tags: cuda

In CUDA, there are two metrics I don't quite understand clearly, which are "requested global load throughput" and "global load throughput".

from [What's the difference between "gld/st_throughput" and "dram_read/write_throughput" metrics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840328/whats-the-difference-between-gld-st-throughput-and-dram-read-write-throughpu) I know the difference between global load throughput and dram load throughput, but what exactly is "requested global load throughput"?

If I want to tell how good my CUDA application behaves in global memory access, which metric should I use?

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae is second what you wrote. Please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Requested* global loads are the loads you, as the programmer, write. This is to distinguish from "effective" global loads that the memory engine performs.

For example, when you load 32 floats from global memory, you are *requesting* a 32x4 bytes global load. If those 32 floats are within the same 128 bytes segment, these 32 loads will be coalesced into a single memory transaction of 128 bytes. But if those floats are scattered, the memory engine may have to do several transactions to load all 32 floats. In the worst case, where all floats are more than 128 bytes from each other, the memory engine will issue 1 transaction per float: you get 32x128 bytes effectively loaded from global memory as opposed to 32x4 requested.

On a related note, the metric `gld_efficiency` is defined as `100 * gld_requested_throughput / gld_throughput`. Therefore it hits 100% when all your accesses are perfectly coalesced. You may want to keep an eye on these different metrics to see how your application performs.